# ruby display 2 dimension array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to display 2 dimension array. using below code. However for each array's first subscript I have to code one loop. Can I do it using an outer loop instead of multiple loops?

```
  <% tempTickets = subject['permailaddr-addrline1'] %>  
  <% cnt = tempTickets.length %>
  <% tempTickets.each_with_index do |ticket, index| %>
<div>
<tr>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['memhead-mem-recno'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['permailaddr-addresstype'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['permailaddr-addrline1'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['permailaddr-state'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['permailaddr-suburb'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['permailaddr-postcode'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['permailaddr-countrycode'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
</tr>
</div>
  <% end %>
  <% tempTickets = subject['perresiaddr-addrline1'] %>  
  <% cnt = tempTickets.length %>
  <% tempTickets.each_with_index do |ticket, index| %>
<div>
<tr>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['memhead-mem-recno'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['perresiaddr-addresstype'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['perresiaddr-addrline1'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['perresiaddr-state'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['perresiaddr-suburb'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['perresiaddr-postcode'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
  <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['perresiaddr-countrycode'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
</tr>
</div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ticketLists = [ subject['permailaddr-addrline1'], subject['perresiaddr-addrline1'] ]

ticketLists.each do |tempTickets|:
```

And then you include the code you want to do for each tempTickets array.

Comment: The number of loops is fine but the values are not coming up properly within the loop. any way to get the values as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try like,

```
 2.times do |i|
    ...
   <%= subject['#{ i==0 ? "permailaddr" : "perresiaddr"}-addresstype'][index] %>
    ...
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
<% ['permailaddr', 'perresiaddr'].each do |prefix| %>
  <% tempTickets.each_with_index do |ticket, index| %>
    <div>
    <tr>
      <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject['memhead-mem-recno'][index] %></span></div></li></td>
      <% ['addresstype', 'addrline1', 'state', 'suburb', 'postcode', 'countrycode'].each do |field_name| %>
        <td><li class="entity_info"><div><span class="label"><%= subject["#{prefix}-#{field_name}"][index] %></span></div></li></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note I've also pulled the field names - `['addresstype', 'addrline1', 'state', 'suburb', 'postcode', 'countrycode']` - out into an array and looped over them, to save some duplicated html - but that's not needed if you don't want it.

Comment: OK, I haven't tested it. The basic concept should work - you may need to modify syntax or something.